# Regarding connected circuits vs disconnected ones

Tags: voltage

so as i understand it, a circuit can be described using 'b' independent equations which are essentially written using KVL and KCL laws- where 'b' refers to the number of unknown currents in a circuit. 
letting n= number of nodes in a circuit

### We look for loops(meshes) and nodes as our big variables in any circuit, and through them, we can solve all the unknowns. Systematically, there are n-1 independent node equations (node voltage method using kcl) and b-(n-1) independent mesh equations(mesh current method using kvl).However, all of this talk apparently applies only to connected circuits which I'm still not exactly sure what it means. And then comes this little excerpt below which I'm not able to fully understand. The textbook suddenly and for the first time introduces the term 'part' along with disconnected circuits which made it confusing.

> The statements pertaining to the number of equations that can be
>   derived from Kirchhoff’s current law, n-1, and voltage law, b-(n-1),
>   apply to connected circuits.  If a circuit has n nodes and b branches
>   and is made up of s parts, the current law can be applied  n - s 
>     times, and the voltage law b – n + s  times.  Any two separate parts
>   can be connected by a single conductor. This connection always causes
>   two nodes to form one node. Moreover, no current exists in the single
>   conductor, so any circuit made up of s disconnected parts can always
>   be reduced to a connected circuit.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please quickly realise this is not a free design house, homework-answering service or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Ask a clear question, show your work and findings so far in considerable detail with any schematic. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a warm welcome to the site

Comment: It is these  theoretical formulae for deriving the number of equations to determine the equal or less number of unknowns.  In Kirchhoff abbreviations we call it KVL and KCL

Comment: @TonyM my bad if it seemed like you described it i will change it right away and hopefully you can help

Comment: @TonyM any better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is true and not very useful for real design.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjesbZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

V1 R1 R2 and I1 R3 are disconnected circuits.

A connection can be made between them without affecting the device voltages or currents.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQbOX5.png)</sup>